# Quantitative Transfer of Volatile Standards

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, vapor-pressure

(Edited w/ updates) Okay, long story short I work in a lab which has been working on cannabinoid analysis (in the licensed Canadian market) and have had a lot of issues surrounding the standards/response factors varying over time.

They are only available in pure methanol or ACN, are very expensive, and only come in $\pu{1 mL}$ quantities. I currently micropipette $\pu{150 \mu L}$ of these into a vial and then dilute, though the vapour pressure of the solvent causes it to immediately push droplets back out of the pipette tip, meaning the volume changes slightly based on the speed at which you transfer, and I think this (among other things, like slow evaporation of retained stocks in storage) is causing variation. Relative response factors between cannabinoids vary up to 30% between different preparations on different days, which is unacceptable.

So I need to both conserve the liquid I use and find a way of transferring that can reduce the effect of volatility. I proposed weighing the ampule, transferring quantitatively to volumetric flask and weighing again, then back calculating the mass amounts using density, as the concentrations come per volume. I was confused about what my manager's issue with the idea was at first but clarified and it was about potential effect of the dissolved cannabinoids on the density of the solution via partial molar volume effects on the manufacturer's end. Aka how much would this affect density and are the concentrations they gave us reliable? They're FDA exempt, meaning they're unregulated and there is no one "gold standard" preparation or test method.

I wrote a pseudo-proof for this effect being negligible (**TL;DR** because 2.5mg solute of any kind out of 786mg solvent would produce a variation of <0.5% in density even when wildly exaggerating the partial molar volume effects) and our chief scientific officer reviewed and signed off on it so I'm going to be doing the gravimetric transfer.

Ampoule chips were not really a concern, they very reliably break cleanly and any chips are likely too small to be seen/matter much on that same ~782mg scale during my preparation.

Comment: What are you using the standard for?

Comment: If you're transferring the entire contents to a volumetric flask, you don't need to mess about with density.  You will have the mass from the ampoule weighings.

Comment: @Beerhunter: The ampule could be chipped and could loose some weights.

Comment: @Night Writer UPLC assay of cannabinoid content from a whole whack of different products. I'm responsible for developing methods to extract and test new dosage forms. Actually get something new in almost every week.

Comment: @Beerhunter Funnily enough, I kept thinking this also. I've since clarified the issue w/ manager and concern was about the expansion or contraction of the stock on the manufacturer's end due to partial molar volume effects. I ended up writing a proof that the effect would be laughably negligible even in a "worst case scenario" and TL;DR we're doing it my way now.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but is concentration that important in UPLC? Are you assaying for concentration? Can you use a different reference if so?

Comment: >though the vapour pressure of the solvent causes it to immediately push droplets back out of the pipette tip, || You can cool the pippette and the ampule in a freezer...

Comment: I am not an analytical chemist, so sorry if the suggestion could be inapprioriate, but do you use the standard without dilution, or you have to dilute it? If you need to dilute it, what about preparing a solution of the sample in a solvent with lower volatility, such as ethylene glycole? (I mean, in order to obtain your standard as a mixed solvent solution, in methanol/glycol)

Comment: How do you detect the cannabinoids?  By UV absorption or by MS or by something else?

Comment: In addition to cooling, when you pipette the 150 uL, first pipette up and down a few times in the source container.  This will fill the headspace of the pipette tip with solvent vapor and reduce evaporation (and thus droplet ejection) in the final step where you do transfer.  Also make sure you are using the right pipette size (e.g. a 200 uL pipette with smaller tips is better than a 1000 mL pipette with bigger tips and bigger aperature for this job.)